# Trigger the ObjectListView cell into editing status from outside

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

We have a win form, there is an `ObjectListView` and a button named `btnOK` on the form. Normally, I can edit a cell by click on the cell in the `ObjectListView` but I want the specify cell go into the editing status (a `TextBox` in the cell and focus on it) by clicking the `btnOK`.

It seems that `ObjectListView` does not support it, as the `CellEventArgs` only provide the properties which support "get" method only, but not provide "set" method.

Is there any possible or any other way to implement my requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that ObjectListView does not support it, as the CellEventArgs only provide the properties which support "get" method only, but not provide "set" method.

Because `CellEventArgs` contains arguments for an `ObjectListView` event (for example `CellEditFinishing`), triggered in response to something that *did* happen. What you need to do is to programmatically start something that *will* happen.

> But I want the specify cell go into the editing status (a textbox in the cell and focuse on it) by click the btnOK.

Simply call `ObjectListView.EditSubItem()` method. First parameter is a reference to list item you want to edit and second parameter which sub-item (*column*...) you want to edit. For example to start editing currently focused item:

```
ctrlList.EditSubItem((OLVListItem)ctrlList.FocusedItem, 0);
```